# PDF CMYK export in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, pdf, cmyk

I'm trying to use the [PDF CMYK export plugin](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/ExportPDFCMYK) for Inkscape, but it fails when I save the document.

I have selected an ICC profile (A `FOGRA39L.icc` profile) and applied it to most of the colors in my document.

When I try saving to a PDF, I get this:

[image: Error saving with PDF CMYK]

Am I doing something wrong? Is this known?

Comment: You should be asking the plug in manufacturer, not here.

Comment: FWIW, [here are some command line alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241282/converting-pdf-to-cmyk-with-identify-recognizing-cmyk).

Comment: Concerning CMYK PDF export in Inkscape (and the extension you mention), see also [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/574717).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the extension is [not supported anymore](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=5943&start=25#p45028) and is replaced by the [outputpro plugin](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=5943&start=25#p45043).

Unfortunately, the outputpro plugin only exports to JPEG currently (and is only in Portuguese).

Comment: FWIW, I fixed the output pro plugin for recent versions of Inkscape: https://github.com/wout/Inkscape-OUTPUT-PRO